# Pine script, is there any way to dynamically set the

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

My indicator has to define a variable `open_time`. And the `open_time` var should be set as the current date time.

However, the `timestamp` function can only accept the const, instead of a dynamic variable. For example, if I can use `timenow` as the variable into `timestamp`, I don't have to set this input var every day, which is clumsy.

Is there any way to handle this?

This is the code:

```
study("Day trade MA", overlay=true)

open_time = input(type=input.time, defval=timestamp("10 Jul 2021 00:00 +0300"), step=1)
```

### Update

What I need is a fixed date time, regardless of moving bars. As I'm using this indicator to do the intraday trading, So currently, I just manually set the date time as the yesterday of the current day.

Comment: Your title appears to be unfinished: "is there any way to dynamically set the" seems to need a noun.

Answer (score 2):

`input` function's `defval=` argument doesn't accept variables and mean to be constant.

You can, however, introduce the input switch to activate user's input of the timestamp, otherwise use the timestamp of the daily candle open, as is shown in the example below:

```
//@version=4
study("Day trade MA", overlay=true)
bool open_time_on = input(false, '', inline = 'open_time')
open_time = input(type=input.time, defval=timestamp("10 Jul 2021 00:00 +0300"), step=1, inline = 'open_time')

var int daily_open = na
daily_open := change(time('D')) ? time : nz(daily_open[1])
open_time_out = open_time_on ? open_time : daily_open

plot(open_time_out, 'open_time_out')
plot(time, 'time', color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, BTW, is there any way to locate yesterday or the day before yesterday instead of timenow?

Comment: Updated the answer, now the script use the input timestamp or daily candle open time.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I forgot to mention, what I need is a fix time value. like 10 Sep, it's for intraday trading, so every day I have to manually set the date as the day before yesterday. it's a fixed date, regardless of moving bars .